# how to get firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP on update operation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unix-timestamp

is it possible to get firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP value after I did  update operation?

my code looks like

```
    return firebase.database().ref('pathurl...').update(newData);
```

and my newData have inside attribute that have 
 firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is it possible to get the TIMESTAMP value that I  push?

Comment: Sure. Just attach a value listener to the same location and read the value back.

Comment: Hi! would you give us a line of code by example? I can't achieve it.